# Why is Dropzone Failing for Large Uploads?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, dropzone.js

`maxAllowedContentLength` and `maxRequestLength` are set in my web.config file; however, large (1.8 GB+) files are still not working for my Dropzone upload. I have previous code that someone else worked on, and that page is working for the same file I'm trying (2.94 GB), but I don't want to revert to the old code unless it's absolutely necessary as it's not as nice as Dropzone. So I know it's Dropzone or the code I'm using to save the file.

```
foreach (string s in Request.Files)
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[s];

            int fileSizeInBytes = file.ContentLength;
            string fileName = file.FileName;
            string fileExtension = file.ContentType;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
            {
                string subDir = "asdf";
                fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                subDir = User.Identity.Name.Split('@')[0];
                fileName = Path.Combine(@"\\rocket\Assets\ftp\", subDir + "\\" + fileName);


                string checkExists = fileName;
                while (File.Exists(checkExists))
                {
                    // get the file name without the extension
                    string[] temp = checkExists.Split('.');
                    string fileNameNoExtention = temp[temp.Length - 2];

                    checkExists = fileNameNoExtention + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString() + fileExtension;
                }

                // IMPORTANT! Make sure to validate uploaded file contents, size, etc. to prevent scripts being uploaded into your web app directory
                file.SaveAs(checkExists);
                Session["fileUploaded"] = checkExists;
            }
        }
```

Is there something wrong with how I'm saving the file, or is Dropzone reaching a limitation?

Answer (score -3):

The dropzone is reaching its limit, i suggest to revert to your old codes as the dropzone cannot meet your needs if large files is what you want

Comment: That's not true at all.

Comment: And not helpful as well.